# How do I convert a List of Chars to a List of Strings in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

So I have a List of Chars
[, *, ] as example, but I want it to be ["","*",""]

How can I make this happen? All I find on the Internet is how to convert a list to a string, but as I said that's not what I want. Any help?

Thanks in advance

Comment: _String(listOfChars.toCharArray())_

Comment: The answer given seems to work. Do accept the answer if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 3):

You only have to use the map function on the list:

```
val strings = listOf('a','b').map{it.toString()}
print(strings)
```